# Discrete Mathematics: inferring the out-degree of a vertex in a digraph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, directed-graphs

Diagram:

[image]

Question:

> Is it possible to infer the out-degree of vertex 4 in $G^+$ from the information given?

I was completely stumped on what to do here. I looked at the solution:

> Yes. There is a walk from vertex 4 to every other vertex in the graph in $G^2$. If there is a walk from 4 to vertex x in $G^2$, then there is a walk from 4 to x in $G$ which implies that $(4, x)$ is an edge in $G^+$.

But I still don't understand the logic. How does the fact that you can draw a walk from $4$ to any other vertex in $G^2$ suggest that you can do the same in $G$?

Comment: To clarify: $G^n$ is like viewing the graph like a matrix and multiplying it? And what's $G^+$?

Comment: I am confused. I thought $G^k$ is the graph that has an edge between $i$ and $j$ if and only if there is a path of length *at most* $k$ in the original $G$ ...

Comment: My book defines $G^+$ as the transitive closure of a graph $G$ and $G^k$ as the digraph where an edge $(u, v)$ exists in $G^k$ if and only if there is a walk of length $k$ from $u$ to $v$ in $G$. Did my book lie? :o

Comment: @AleksandrH OK, that's what I assumed in my Answer I just posted as well.

Comment: I can't help wondering if you can outfer the in-degree ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, make sure not to confuse *edges* with *walks*.

I suppose $G^2$ is the graph that has an edge from $i$ to $j$ if and only if there is a walk of length $2$ from $i$ to $j$ in the original graph $G$

I also assume that $G^+$ is the graph that shows an edge from $i$ to $j$ if there is a walk of any length from $i$ to $j$ in the original graph (this is the same as taking the transitive closure of $G$).

Well, then it makes sense that if there is a walk in $G^2$ from $i$ to $j$, then there is a walk of length $2n$ in $G$ from $i$ to $j$, and hence there will be an edge from $i$ to $j$ in $G^+$

For example, in $G^2$ there is a walk from $4$ to $2$: $4 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2$

Now, the edge of $4$ to $3$ in $G^2$ means that there is a walk of length $2$ in the original $G$. We don't know which vertex this walk goes through, but it has to be *some* vertex in $G$. Same for the edge in $G^2$ from $3$ to $1$, and from $1$ to $2$, so we know there is a walk in $G$ that looks like:

$4 \rightarrow ? \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow ? \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow ? \rightarrow 2$

So, there is a walk from $4$ to $2$ in $G$, and therefore an edge from $4$ to $2$ in $G^+$

Comment: The book uses the term "walk" instead of "path", since it's not necessary that no vertices be repeated. So in $G^2$, an edge exists from $i$ to $j$ iff there is a walk of length $2$ from $i$ to $j$ in $G$.

Comment: @AleksandrH OK, that makes sense, for if you look at my answer, you'll see that by filling in some of the ?'s you can (in fact, you have to, since there are only 5 vertices) go through the same vertex multiple times. I'll change path to walk in my Answer.

Comment: Thanks! Revisiting this question, what does this tell us about the out degree of the vertex 4? What if the vertex 4 only has an edge going to a single other vertex, but that vertex then connects to all the others, thereby allowing us to form the walks of the necessary lengths?

Comment: @AleksandrH You mean for the original $G$, right?  Well, if the graph $G$ would be like what you say, then there would be a walk of length $2$ from $4$ to every vertex, and that would mean that there would have to be an edge in $G^2$ to every other vertex (including itself).  Since there is not, we know the original graph $G$ does not look like what you just said.  In fact, with the only outgoing edge in $G^2$ from $4$ is one going to $3$, we know that the only vertex that you can reach from $4$ in exactly two steps in $G$ is $3$.

Comment: Hmm, all right. Just having trouble digesting/picturing all this.

Comment: @AleksandrH Yeah, it is really quite a nasty problem to figure out $G$ (or at least parts thereof) on the basis of $G^2$ and $G^3$ (or at least, I my self am not an expert on this .. maybe there are some algorithms for this out there, but I wouldn't know them).  Anyway, there are *some* thing you can figure out.  For example, we know that in $G$ there cannot be an edge from any vertex to itself, because then in $G^2$ there would be an edge form every vertex to itself as well, and there isn't.  Likewise, if there is an edge in $G$ from $i$ to $j$, then there is not an edge from $j$ to $i$ ...

Comment: @AleksandrH Do you see why?  We also know it is a connected graph .. do you why that is true as well?

Comment: @AleksandrH Hmmm, maybe it is easiest to *first* figure out what edges do *not* exist in $G$. For example, there cannot be an edge from $2$ to either $3$ , since if there was, then given that in $G^2%$ there is an edge from $1$ to $2$, then in $G^3$ there should have been an edge from $1$ to $3$

Comment: @AleksandrH OK, so I made a mistake earlier, and it turns out you cannot determine the *whole* graph $G$, but a good chunk of it. It is not enough to determine the out-degree of $4$ though ....

Comment: Yeah, I'm totally lost on all this :(

Comment: What I was saying before is that a walk is defined as a sequence of steps from one vertex to another, with multiple possible destinations in between. For example, if you can reach vertex 2 from vertex 4, why does that mean vertex 4 necessarily has an out-arrow towards vertex 2? Vertex 4 could theoretically point to all other vertices except 2, but those other vertices may very well bridge the gap with 2, thereby allowing a walk from 4 to 2.

Comment: Ahhhh, I just got it! Okay. So the transitive closure has an edge (arrow) pointing from one vertex (call it a) to another (call it b) if it is possible to reach "b" from "a" by a walk of any length. My mistake was trying to infer the out-degree of vertex 4 in G instead of the transitive closure, G+. Sorry for any confusion :)

Comment: @AleksandrH Oh, that's funny, I was trying to figure out what $G$ was as well, instead of $G^+$ !  $G^+$ is of course the fully connected graph. BUt I was able to figure out a good chunk of $G$ as well ... but you cannot figure out all of $G$ ... but furtuntaely the question wasn't about $G$

Comment: :) Yep, thanks again!